# pattern match issue with SpaCy

Tags: spacy

I have the following script using a pattern to match the postcode. However, depending on how I supply the postcode string seems to affect how it is matched.

```py
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
import en_core_web_lg

nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()

patterns = [
    {
        "label": "POST_CODE", "pattern": [
            {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r'^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?$'}}, 
            {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r'^\d[a-zA-Z]{2}$'}}
            ]
        }
    ]
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", config={"validate": True})
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)


def get_entities(text):
    entTypes = []
    doc = nlp(text)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        x = {}
        x[entity.label_] = entity.text
        entTypes.append(x)

    return {"entities": entTypes}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(get_entities(sys.argv[1]))
```

Samples:

```
python test.py "this is a test RH15 9XR"
{'entities': [{'CARDINAL': '9XR'}]}
```

```
python test.py "this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG"
{'entities': [{'CARDINAL': '9XR'}, {'POST_CODE': 'RH4 9GG'}]}
```

```
python test.py "this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG, RH5 0XE"
{'entities': [{'CARDINAL': '9XR'}, {'POST_CODE': 'RH4 9GG'}, {'POST_CODE': 'RH5 0XE'}]}
```

```
python test.py "this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG, RH5 0XE PO01 0IO"
{'entities': [{'CARDINAL': '9XR'}, {'POST_CODE': 'RH4 9GG'}, {'CARDINAL': '0XE'}, {'CARDINAL': '0IO'}]}
```

It would appear that for some reason the first postcode is never matched. In the last example both "RH5 0XE" & "PO01 0IO" should match, as you can see "RH5 0XE" matched in the previous run.

Any ideas on how I can improve the match rate?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `entity_ruler` before `ner` in the pipeline so that its matches have priority over the `CARDINAL` spans from `ner`, or alternatively you can set it to overwrite overlapping entities with the `overwrite_ents` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the regex with re instead of through spacy does it work?

I think you are not handling white spaces or end of string / start of string situations correctly in your regex -- all the examples where your test works have commas nearby while the examples failing have less commas around them

Comment: Yes the regex is fine as a standalone regex. I am not sure how to control what is passed to the regex as that is controlled by SpaCy.

Comment: Just to confirm when you run it with re you get all the tests passing?

Comment: Yes the following pattern on [regex101](regex101.com)
 "[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?\s\d[a-zA-Z]{2}"

Matches the following patterns:

```
this is a test RH15 9XR
this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG
this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG, RH5 0XE
this is a test RH15 9XR, RH4 9GG, RH5 0XE PO01 0IO
```